# select focusses and blocks further execution on iPhone 5

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile

In a Jquery Mobile app, I have a problem which only occurs on iPhone 5 devices. Other iPhone versions (at least above 5) and all other platforms has no problem.
Inside a page I have a dialog. In the dialog there are a few selects.
When the OK button or Cancel button (tsBtnOK, tsBtnCancel) is clicked the select width id 'transJobType' is brought into focus and awaits user selection, execution stops.
The code of tbBtnOK is never executed. The same happens with no code to run on the tsBtnOK.

I have tried:

- data-menu-native false/true no difference
- data-prevent-focus-zoom, false/true no difference
- coded focus to the tsBtnOK, no difference

Remember this only occurs on the iPhone 5 platform, but is consistent over all (3+) iPhone 5 devices I have tested on.

It seems that when the two panels: 'transWorkTypeDiv' and 'transDescriptionDiv' is hidden it works, in the sense that the select is still displayed shortly, but the code on the tsBtnOK is executed and the dialog closes when done.

Note that the markup is part of an ASPX page, so thats the reason for the 
<%=GetLocalResourceObject...> tags

Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated

```
<div data-role="popup" id="tsTransDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-transition="flip" data-position-to="window" data-theme="<%=global_asax.JQMTheme%>" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetTransDiaHeader") %></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                <div id="tsTransDialogFields">
                    <div id="divWorkSelect" class="jobOnly ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="transJobType"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetJobType") %></label>
                        <select name="transJobType" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="true" data-prevent-focus-zoom="true" onchange="tsOpenJobPicker();" id="transJobType">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jobOnly" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="transJobNo"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetJobNo") %></label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" data-inline="true" id="transJobNo" placeholder="<%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetExampleJobNo") %>" />
                            <div style="position: absolute; top: 25px; right: -4px">
                                <a href="javascript:tsOpenJobPicker();" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="search"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="transStartTimeDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="transStartTime"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetStartTime") %></label>
                        <input type="text" data-inline="true" id="transStartTime" placeholder="<%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetExampleTime") %>13:05" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="transStopTimeDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="transStopTime"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetStopTime") %></label>
                        <input type="text" data-inline="true" id="transStopTime" placeholder="<%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetExampleTime") %>14:55" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="transHoursDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="transHours"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetHours") %></label>
                        <input type="text" data-inline="true" id="transHours" placeholder="<%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetExampleTime") %> 2,5" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="transWorkTypeDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="selectTransWorkType"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetWorkType") %></label>
                        <select name="selectTransWorkType" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="true" data-prevent-focus-zoom="true"  id="selectTransWorkType"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="transDescriptionDiv">
                        <div id="transDescriptionDiv1" data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="transDescription1"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetTransDescription1") %></label>
                            <input type="text" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="transDescription1" name="transDescription1" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="transDescriptionDiv2" data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="transDescription2"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetTransDescription2") %></label>
                            <input type="text" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="transDescription2" name="transDescription2" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a id="tsBtnOK" href="javascript:tsTransInsert();" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="<%=global_asax.JQMTheme%>"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TimesheetTransUpdate") %></a>
                <a id="tsBtnCancel" href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="<%=global_asax.JQMTheme%>"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Cancel") %></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, which is by no means logic, but I will answer my own question in case other people should find themselves in the same situation and stumble on this.
I moved the dialog tsTransDialog outside the page, as a shared dialog, and initiate it on startup. 
It made the problem disappear.